# Selenium with hudson:firefox browser is not getting lanuched while selenium scripts are running through hudson

Tags: selenium

i integrated my selenium scripts (using junit) with Hudson. i invoked my job through ant . My problem was my scripts are running successfully but the fire fox browser is not getting opened. At this moment i am not using selenium grid .please provide any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you run Hudson as a service using your own account. If you want to see Firefox browser you must select Local System Account as a service runner (Log on option in service properties) Then there is a possibility to check interact with desktop checkbox and it makes browser "visible" while running your tests.

Comment: This solved my issue but I don't have the option for "interact with desktop" to get Firefox visible when tests are running...